# Correct DHCP client configuration

Tags: dhcp, dhclient

I have two dhcp directories in /etc: /etc/dhcp and /etc/dhcp3
Which one is the correct direcotry for editing my dhcp client configuration?

I want to send the hostname with dhcp and so was trying to set the correct hostname in the dhclient.conf. But this file only exists in /etc/dhcp but not in /etc/dhcp3.

Comment: Possible dupe of [How do I configure a DHCP server?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140126/how-do-i-configure-a-dhcp-server) and [dhcpserver configuration, please help](http://askubuntu.com/questions/461329/dhcpserver-configuration-please-help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out which packages own (are responsible for the creation of) each directory: `dpkg -S /etc/dhcp;dpkg -S /etc/dhcp3`. I would guess that, if the `/etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf` file does not exist, you cannot edit it. Edit the one you have.